# Extreme points of radical function

Tags: functions

$$\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}$$ I need to find the extreme points for this. I found that the derivate is $$\frac{-2+\sqrt{x-1}}{2\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}} $$ .What kind of point is (5,0) and why? for 5 the limit of the derivate is 0 on both sides.Is this an inflection point?

Comment: The derivative is undefined at $x=5$. The derivative from the left is $-1/4$, and from the right it's $+1/4$.

Comment: Point$(1,2)$ is a cusp, partially, just like in $y=\sqrt x$ in the origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x-1-4\sqrt{x-1}+4}=|\sqrt{x-1}-2|$$
and we don't need derivatives because for $x\geq5$ we get
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}-2,$$ which is increasing

and for $1\leq x\leq5$ we get
$$f(x)=2-\sqrt{x-1},$$ which is decreasing.

Thus, $x_{min}=5$.

$(5,0)$ is an angular point because $$f'\left(5^+\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}_{x=5}=\frac{1}{4},$$
$$f'\left(5^-\right)=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}_{x=5}=-\frac{1}{4}$$
and $\frac{1}{4}\neq-\frac{1}{4}$.

The maximum does not exist.

Comment: In my book it says its an angular point,I think this is how it is translated.Could you tell me why?

Comment: But shouldn't an angular point have a finite limit in 5 such that f' limit left is different than f' limit right?

Comment: @Lola I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: Thank you, Ifinally got it,I didn't see I could write it like that and no matter how I tried the derivate in 5 always had an undeterminate form.

Comment: @Lola You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}$. Then $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ and $f(5)=0$.

Hence $f$ has at $x=5$ the global minimum.